# Tooling API - query Attachment

Tags: soap-api, attachment, tooling-api

I'm using Salesforce Tooling API in my C# application. When I'm trying to run the query:

```
var res = sforce.query("select id from Attachment where parentid = '" + id + "'");
```

I get the following error:

> INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Attachment' is not supported.

I can query `Attachment` only when using Partner API, but then I can get only `sObject[]` as there is no `Attachment` type in wsdl.
I am logged in as System Administrator.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooling API is not meant for querying records or accessing salesforce data

Check [this salesforce article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_tasks.htm) for when to use Tooling API

You can definitely use Query method via standard enterprise / partner APIs to access [Attachment object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm).

**EDIT :**

Yes, as you guessed, **partner wsdl** is loosely coupled and meant for flexible client implementations, which means you will have some work on parsing/type casting the results..

on the other side **enterprise wsdl** is strongly typed and will get you all the proxy classes you need to access from your client app.

you can also consider using the [Force.com .NET Toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) which abstracts most of this and keeps your integration simple.

and to your question on **attachment** object in tooling api, I believe it refers to email template attachments. If you do a search for attachment in the tooling api wsdl, the only reference is in the metadata part of **emailtemplate** type.

[image]

Comment: Ok, as I understand it now, there are no strongly typed objects at all in Partner API. One have to query the result from `sObject.Any` property, and it is just a raw XML. I'm still wondering why there is `Attachment` type in Tooling api (it has the `byte[] body` property). It's a bit confusing. I must say that querying Xml with linq to get the attachment is not the most comfortable approach.